# How to reorganize a pandas dataframe according to a column content

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reshape a pandas dataframe to display properties of a single object (column1) that are organized line by line into a single line per object with multiple columns and NaNs in case the properties are missing, like the second table.

[image: Input table]

[image: Expected output]

I've found the exactly opposite (pd.melt) but so far couldn't reverse the process.

Comment: can you paste your dataframe instead of putting a screenshot?

Comment: use this and then change the column names: `final=df.set_index(['Column1',df.groupby('Column1').cumcount()]).unstack().sort_index(level=1,axis=1).reset_index()` and then `final.columns=[f"Column{i}" for i in range(1,final.shape[1]+1)]`

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I solved it with: <code>df.pivot(index='Column1', columns='Column3', values='Column2')